# vertical Align content in merged rows

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm writing a code where there are some rows to be merged. Using POI, I've achieved doing this. But the problem is after merging the rows I need to make them center.

Below is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\D\\Sheets\\Sample Sheets\\dummy.xls"));
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fin);
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        int row = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        String currentLawName, currentCountry, currentAssociate, previousLawName, previousCountry, previousAssociate;
        String currentPages, previousPages;
        int startIndex = 1, finalIndex = 0, tempNum = 0;
        System.out.println(row);
        for (int i = 2; i < (row); i++) {
            currentAssociate = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).toString();
            currentLawName = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(1).toString();
            currentCountry = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(2).toString();
            currentPages = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(3).toString();

            previousAssociate = sheet.getRow(i - 1).getCell(0).toString();
            previousLawName = sheet.getRow(i - 1).getCell(1).toString();
            previousCountry = sheet.getRow(i - 1).getCell(2).toString();
            previousPages = sheet.getRow(i - 1).getCell(3).toString();

            if (currentAssociate.equals(previousAssociate) && currentCountry.equals(previousCountry)
                    && currentLawName.equals(previousLawName) && currentPages.equals(previousPages)) {
                finalIndex += 1;
                if (((i + 1) == row)) {
                    System.out.println("yes");
                    finalIndex += 1;
                    sendRangeToMergeCells(startIndex + 1, finalIndex - 1, sheet);
                }
            } else {
                sendRangeToMergeCells(startIndex + 1, finalIndex, sheet);
                startIndex = i;
                finalIndex = 0;
            }

        }
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("C:\\D\\Sheets\\Sample Sheets\\dummy.xls");
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    }

    private static void sendRangeToMergeCells(int startIndex, int finalIndex, HSSFSheet sheet) {
        System.out.println("B:" + startIndex + "\tB:" + (finalIndex + startIndex) + "\t else");
        CellRangeAddress region = CellRangeAddress.valueOf("D" + (startIndex) + ":D" + ((finalIndex + startIndex)));
        sheet.addMergedRegion(region);
    }
```

please let me know how can I vertically center the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add alignment (and other properties) to a cell, you need to set the `CellStyle`.

There are a number of ways to do this, but in your case, you already have a cell with content (that would be the upper left corner of the merged region), so you can use `CellUtil.setProperty()`.

```
CellUtil.setCellProperty(cell, CellUtil.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT, CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);
```

If you need to set multiple properties at once, you should use `CellUtil.setCellProperties()`

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

// border around a cell
properties.put(CellUtil.BORDER_TOP, CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
properties.put(CellUtil.BORDER_BOTTOM, CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
properties.put(CellUtil.BORDER_LEFT, CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
properties.put(CellUtil.BORDER_RIGHT, CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);

// Give it a color (RED)
properties.put(CellUtil.TOP_BORDER_COLOR, IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
properties.put(CellUtil.BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR, IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
properties.put(CellUtil.LEFT_BORDER_COLOR, IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());
properties.put(CellUtil.RIGHT_BORDER_COLOR, IndexedColors.RED.getIndex());

// Apply it to a cell     
CellUtil.setCellStyleProperties(cell, properties);
```

Read more in the Apache POI Quick Guide: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html